# Merge 2 Dataframes using properties

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df :

```
symbol   date          close 
aa       01/02/2019    23
aa       01/03/2019    22
aa       01/04/2019    21
ab       01/02/2019    25
.
.
.
```

and I have another dataframe df2

```
symbol Oher_columns 
aa        .
ab        .
ac
ad
.
.
.
```

There are a lot of entries in df1 about symbol that are not present in df2. I want to merge the two datasets such that I want to get the close value for each symbol for a date 01/02/2019. I am not able to understand how to use join in this case.

The output would be df3 :

```
symbol    close 
aa          23
ab          22
ac          21
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter `df1` first

```
out=df2.merge(df1.loc[df1.date=='01/02/2019'],on='symbol')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However, this merges all the other columns as well to the df2. I want to add only close to the df2 and if the value of close in df1 is not present, then should fill NA to it. I hope this clarifies more.